# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, django

I am learning ajax with Django. This is my code but it logs **SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1** in my console.I tried editing the **csrf_token** part but nothing good could come. What can be the possible glitches in my code?

index.html

```
...
<form class="form-inline" action="translate/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="textarea" class="form-control email" id="email" placeholder="Enter text" name="string" autofocus="">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Convert</button>
        </form>
...
<script>
    var csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
    $("#email").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: '/translate/',
        data: {
          "value": value,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(":)");
            console.log(data);
          {#$("#googletrans").html(data.googletrans);#}
        },
          error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          alert(error);
          console.log(error);
       }
      });

    });
</script>
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def convert(request):
    value = request.GET.get('value', None)
    data = {
        "googletrans":  "prateek"
    }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^translate/$', views.convert, name='convert'),
]
```

Comment: I typically find an unexpected < means that your request is hitting a page not found or something along those lines and the < is the beginning of an HTML document instead of a JSON response.  Run fiddler and watch the request/response, that'll tell you what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks.Can you tell me why is my code returning an HTML response?

Comment: Why you are sending `POST` request in ajax but trying to get `value` from `request.GET`?

Comment: What is the `responseText` from your `xhr` object in error function? You can try to send the POST request with postman or other restclient and see what actually returned from server.

Answer (score 0):

I think your error may be in your URL definitions.
Try to change the first pattern from `''` to `'^/'`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^/', views.home, name='home'),
    ...
]
```